# Statistics Question: Do I eliminate fringe cases from my analysis?

Tags: statistics

I am trying to analyze the sale multiple for businesses in general.

Here's how my sample data looks like:

[image]

As you can see Business e sold for multiple which was much higher than rest of the samples.

And assuming such high multiples are not not frequently attainable, should I keep business e in my general market data or should I eliminate it to get a better picture of the market?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, removing apparent 'outliers' from data is a bad idea.
Observations *known* to be the result of data entry error,
equipment failure (e.g, IQ entered as 199 instead of 99) may be removed. Also, *obviously impossible* results (e.g, height -35 cm, human age 933 years) may be deleted.

Sometimes, boxplots are used to detect 'outliers' for which
values need to be investigated. However, such outliers are an
ordinary feature of many distributions, including normal ones.
Here are boxplots for 20 samples of size $n=200.$ [Outliers are plotted as detached dots.]

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(4000, 100, 15)
gp = rep(1:20, each=200)
boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

Almost all of the 20 samples show at least one boxplot outlier
and most show several. It is true that most of the observations
from a normal population lie in $\mu \pm 3\sigma,$ but the
tails of the normal distribution extend to $\pm\infty.$

If you fear that some unusual observations may interfere with
correct estimation of population parameters, you might use
so-called robust methods. For example, a '5% trimmed mean'
*temporarily* disregards the top and bottom 5% of sorted
observations, and takes the mean of the central 90%.
For example, consider the following waiting times for a
particular event to occur, exponentially distributed with
population mean $\mu = 10.$

```
set.seed(1776)
y = rexp(100, .1)
boxplot(y, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

```
mean(y);  mean(y, tr=.05) 
[1] 11.88836
[1] 11.05303
```

In this particular sample, the trimmed mean happens to be closer to $\mu = 10$
than is the (ordinary) mean.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation. Thank you!